# Is it possible to convert vector valued function in this form: $r(t)=\langle3,t,t^2-1\rangle$ into non parametric form?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

For instance with $r(t)=\langle t+1, t^2-2\rangle$, we can substitute it with x values and y values to get $y=t^2-2=(x-1)^2-2$ form that is easy to graph. How can we do the same for $r(t)=\langle 3,t,t^2-1\rangle$?

I managed to sub $z=y^2-1$, but not sure where to place the $x=3$ in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to represent that curve in a non-parametric way is, as already observed in other answers, as a **pair** of equations: $z=y^2-1, x=3$.

If one is been stubborn, a rather convoluted way to obtain a **single** equation could be

$$(y^2-z-1)^2+(x-3)^2=0$$

or may be

$$|y^2-z-1|+|x-3|=0$$

but those are just artificial and more complicated ways to join the two equations and should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you have it ! What you need to plot is the function of equation $z=y^2-1$, plotted in the $yz$ plane of equation $x=3$. Here is a drawing (using online Geogebra 3D, equation : $(3,y,y^2-1)$).

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how can we plot this in say a 3D grapher/calculator, in this form Z(x,y)=?

Answer (score 2):

You've got a parabola $z=y^2-1$ in the $y-z$ plane, translated three units parallel to that plane.  So it isn't a surface,  but rather $1$-dimensional.  There's only one free variable.

Comment: Thanks I'm a little confused about "dimensional" here. Isn't it at the very least a 2D graph on the YZ plane? Why is it categorised as 1 dimensional, doesn't the Z axis also count as a dimension?

Comment: Well my point is just that $x$ is fixed so the whole thing can be described with $1$ parameter.   It's basically just the translation of a *curve* in a plane.  Curves are $1-$ dimensional.   If you could write it as a single equation with the $3$ variables $x,y,z$, it would be some type of *surface* (I imagine).

Comment: So, it's something one dimensional,  a curve, sitting in three dimensional space.

Comment: Thanks. How can we express the x=3 part in $z=y^2-1$? It seems to omit that fact that $r(t)=\langle 3,t,t^2-1\rangle$ is a curve/line in 3d space?

Comment: Well I noticed someone found a way,  namely @jjagmath, to write it in a single equation.   This surprised me a little,  but it seems to work.

Comment: Ah that helps, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Your curve $r(t)$ (dimension 1) is immersed in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is said that the codimension is 3-1=2. Then, you need two implicit expressions to properly describe your curve. In this case, is the intersection of two surfaces:
$$
z=y^2-1
$$
and the plane
$$
x=3
$$

By the way, a surface (dimension 2) has codimension 3-2=1, so you only need 1 equation. The intersection of surfaces is a curve (in general).